# Why does git mergetool open 4 windows in vimdiff? (I'd expect 3)

Tags: git, vim, vimdiff

When I met a conflict, I tried to use `git-mergetool` to solve it. I typed:

```
>git mergetool -t vimdiff
```

It opened `vimdiff` in 4-way, not 3-way. My split windows in vimdiff look like:

```
:ls
  1 #a   "Gemfile.lock"                 line 1
  2 %a   "Gemfile.lock.LOCAL.4828.lock" line 1
  3  a   "Gemfile.lock.BASE.4828.lock"  line 0
  4  a   "Gemfile.lock.REMOTE.4828.lock" line 0
```

What are they? I want a 3-way diff: target file, merge file and working file. How should I configure my git or vimdiff?

Comment: No one seems to have pointed this out to you: you need four windows to perform a 3-way diff if you also want the merge-result window to show.  In other words, you get a diff between BASE, LOCAL and REMOTE (3 windows), and the possibility to edit the resulting merge (the 4th window).

Comment: @Magnus with fugitive and meld it is absolutely possible to resolve a 3-way conflict with 3 windows - the local and merge result is in the middle see this [vimcast for fugitive](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-resolving-merge-conflicts-with-vimdiff/) and this [blog post for meld](https://blog.wuwon.id.au/painless-merge-conflict-resolution-in-git/)

Comment: Actually the [fugitive issue #1306](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/1306) explains this perfectly. You have `LOCAL ║ BASE/MERGED ║ REMOTE`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As an alternative, have you thought about using [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)?

> I'm not going to lie to you; fugitive.vim may very well be the best
> Git wrapper of all time.

There is a an excellent vimcast, [Fugitive.vim - resolving merge conflicts with vimdiff](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-resolving-merge-conflicts-with-vimdiff/), by Drew Neil. This is part of a series on fugitive.

The [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) website is a good place to learn more about vim.

To use fugitive as you mergetool you can use the following.

```
git config --global mergetool.fugitive.cmd 'vim -f -c "Gvdiffsplit!" "$MERGED"'
git config --global merge.tool fugitive
```

Note: you may want to change `vim` to `mvim` or `gvim`.

Fugitive has a lot more to offer than just being a merge tool script so make sure you read the documentation and/or check out the vimcasts.

Comment: Can I use it with `git-mergetool`?? It tells me open the conflict file and call `:Gdiff`.

Comment: @Lai Yu-Hsuan: I have edited my post to include some mergetool config options

Comment: Great. Solved my question prefectly.

Comment: Maybe this eliminates the need to BeyondCompare for me, thanks

Comment: I'm hoping this answer becomes the de-facto standard for all git mergetool questions. fugitive + vim + vimcasts + git mergetool is a truly awesome combination of tools and people.

Comment: This answer is referred to in [vim-fugitive issue #1306](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/1306)

Comment: The [issue #1306](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/1306) also has an alternative cmd `git config --global mergetool.fugitive.cmd 'nvim -f -c "Gvdiffsplit!" "$MERGED"'`

Answer (score 10):

After lots of research for issuing mergetool with vimdiff and only 3 windows, I came up with this configuration, that allows me to chose when I want 3 windows or the default 4 windows:

```
git config --global merge.tool vimdiff
git config --global alias.mt mergetool

git config --global mergetool.merge3.cmd 'vim -d -c "wincmd l" "$LOCAL" "$MERGED" "$REMOTE"'
git config --global alias.m3 'mergetool -t merge3'
```

Now you can start 3 windows just typing:

```
git m3
```

And the default (4 windows) will still works as expected with:

```
git mt
```

Also, you probably would like to add this lines to the end of your `~/.vimrc` or `/etc/vim/vimrc`

```
 " shortcuts to vimdiff
 let mapleader=','
 let g:mapleader=','

 if &diff
    map <leader>1 :diffget LOCAL<CR>
    map <leader>2 :diffget BASE<CR>
    map <leader>3 :diffget REMOTE<CR>
 endif
```

This will create shortcuts like `,1` to grab from left, `,3` to grab from right (in both modes) and also `,2` to grab from base (center window) in the 4 windows mode.

That helps a lot!

My `~/.gitconfig` file looks like this:

```
[user]
        name = Dr Beco
        email = my@email
[merge]
        tool = vimdiff
[mergetool "merge3"]
        cmd = vim -d -c \"wincmd l\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$MERGED\" \"$REMOTE\"
[alias]
        lo = log --pretty=format:\"%h %ce %cd %s\" --graph
        co = checkout
        ci = commit
        cm = commit -a -m
        st = status
        br = branch
        m3 = mergetool -t merge3
        mt = mergetool
[diff]
        tool = vimdiff
```

I hope this helps you (and those who get to here).

Answer (score 8):

Note: while you can use only 3 Windows as described in [Dr Beco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670521/dr-beco)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19780597/6309)
(`vim -d -c "wincmd l" "$LOCAL" "$MERGED" "$REMOTE"'`),
**the 4-windows mode is enhanced with git 2.8** (March 2016)

See [commit 2300328](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2300328cb209762a14e32525cfaa91778681f059) (29 Jan 2016) by [Dickson Wong (`diwo`)](https://github.com/diwo).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 82c17b7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82c17b7a9ae1c78ce4891ad272f78fd2cd181ded), 17 Feb 2016)</sup>

> The `vimdiff` backend for "`git mergetool`" has been tweaked to arrange
> and number buffers in the order that would match the expectation of
> majority of people who read left to right, then top down and assign
> buffers 1 2 3 4 "mentally" to local base remote merge windows based
> on that order.

Internally, git will now use:

```
"$merge_tool_path" -f -d -c '4wincmd w | wincmd J' \
            "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
```

instead of:

```
"$merge_tool_path" -f -d -c 'wincmd J' \
        "$MERGED" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE"
```

> ### `mergetool`: reorder vim/gvim buffers in three-way diffs

> When invoking default (g)`vimdiff` three-way merge, the merged file is
> loaded as the first buffer but moved to the bottom as the fourth window.
> This causes a disconnect between `vim` commands that operate on window
> positions (e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W_w</kbd>) and those that operate on buffer index (e.g. <kbd>do</kbd>/<kbd>dp</kbd>).
>
> **This change reorders the buffers to have the same index as windows while
> keeping the cursor default to the merged result as the bottom window.**

---

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), mergetools help considering only 3 panels, not 4.

See [commit 30bb808](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30bb8088afd4502acd2e166ddf7e4b071e53b86d) (13 Feb 2021) by [Seth House (`whiteinge`)](https://github.com/whiteinge).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cadae71](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cadae717d557840d3566b7c0fc2003046e08c88f), 25 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`mergetools/vimdiff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30bb8088afd4502acd2e166ddf7e4b071e53b86d): add vimdiff1 merge tool variant
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Seth House</sup>
> <sup>Tested-by: David Aguilar</sup>

> This adds yet another vimdiff/gvimdiff variant and presents conflicts as a two-way diff between 'LOCAL' and 'REMOTE'.
> 'MERGED' is not opened which deviates from the norm so usage text is echoed as a Vim message on startup that instructs the user with how to proceed and how to abort.
>
> Vimdiff is well-suited to two-way diffs so this is an option for a more simple, more streamlined conflict resolution.
> For example: it is difficult to communicate differences across more than two files using only syntax highlighting; default vimdiff commands to get and put changes between buffers do not need the user to manually specify a source or destination buffer when only using two buffers.
>
> Like other merge tools that directly compare 'LOCAL' with 'REMOTE', this tool will benefit when paired with the new `mergetool.hideResolved` setting.

---

[Arthur Bowers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4482816/arthur-bowers) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309707/why-does-git-mergetool-open-4-windows-in-vimdiff-id-expect-3/35482243?noredirect=1#comment126529708_35482243) having used:

> ```
> git config --global mergetool.vimdiff.cmd \
> '$merge_tool_path -f -d -c "4wincmd w | \
>  wincmd J" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"'
> ```

Comment: THANK YOU! This comment saved my sanity. 


Somehow, I had gotten git to not have the merged pane as default, and googling for how to get it back just leads to lots of pages and guides on how to do 3 way merges, even how to REMOVE the MERGED pane, but it was this comment pointing out the internal usage that allowed me to get my beloved MERGED pane back.
    

Once again, thank you!

Anyone else having this problem, I can post the command that solved it for me if needed.

Comment: @ArthurBowers I would be interested in the command you used indeed.

Comment: here you go


`git config --global mergetool.vimdiff.cmd '$merge_tool_path -f -d -c "4wincmd w | wincmd J" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"'`

Comment: @ArthurBowers Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 5):

Modifying a bit the commands from [this page](http://www.toofishes.net/blog/three-way-merging-git-using-vim/):

```
git config --global mergetool.vimdiff3.cmd 'vim -f -d "$LOCAL" "$MERGED" "$REMOTE"'
git config --global merge.tool vimdiff3
```

- 'Merged' would be your working copy.
- 'Local' the file that is in the branch you are trying to make the changes
- 'Remote' the file from the branch you are trying to merge with.

And then you execute the command: `git mergetool`.

**Note**: I use *fugitive* also and highly recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

I'll second the fugitive recommendation.

You could also try out [splice.vim](https://github.com/sjl/splice.vim). It's a Vim plugin designed to act as a git or mercurial mergetool drop-in replacement. It allows you to easily shuffle various views of the conflict. It's also very quick, straightforward and does a good job at making merging more intuitive. Here's a [screencast](http://vimeo.com/25764692).

The files you've listed are:

1. The local file containing the conflict.
2. The file in the branch you're merging into.
3. The file in the branch you're merging from.
4. The file as it was in both branch ancesestor node. This file is very useful for figuring out what's going on!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Threesome is now called splice.vim