# Git Fast-Forward Merge requires a pull first

Tags: git, merge, push

I have a remote repo which i have changed the last time i cloned it.

The local Repo also change some of the files in my local repo.

What i would like to do is push to origin master, but it says that i need to do a pull first.

Answer (score 2):

git does not push the local changes until the server changes has pull and merged with local.
so when you going to push the local changes then git prompt to pull (merge) server changes first.

git pull  
then
git push

Comment: again, git pull causes conflicts, how do i resolve, lets say one file has been changed nothing else, you do a pull now what?

Answer (score 1):

About the conflicts you can see on a `git pull`, see "[How do I resolve a conflict after git pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435754/how-do-i-resolve-a-conflict-after-git-pull)".
You can [solve a merge conflict manually](http://kernel.mirrors.pair.com/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#resolving-a-merge).

If your git opens vim, check your mergetool settings: "[My git mergetool open 4(not 3) windows in vimdiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309707/my-git-mergetool-open-4not-3-windows-in-vimdiff)".

Once all conflicts (triggered by the `git pull`) are resolved, added and committed, *then* you can `git push`.
This will add new commits to the remote repo history, making the push result in a fast-foward merge on the remote side.

Answer (score 0):

Type:

```
git pull
```

to fetch the remote changes, and merge them with your changes.
Resolve any conflicts which arise, and then type

```
git push
```

to send your local changes (plus the new merge commits) back upstream.

Comment: how do i resolve the conflicts? say i need to fix one file? it loads up vim and i can't use vim.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git