# Git -push error

Tags: git, git-push

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git Fast-Forward Merge requires a pull first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724580/git-fast-forward-merge-requires-a-pull-first)

```
     Pushing to git@github.com:ravi-saxena/locpla.git
```

**Error :**

```
To git@github.com:ravi-saxena/locpla.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:ravi-saxena/locpla.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I am getting this error while pushing the new repository that i recently created..

Comment: Git recommends that you run `git pull`. Have you?

Comment: You should include the output from that as well.

Comment: @Moshe how to slove this

Comment: Are you sure you are working in the `master` branch?

Comment: yes i am working in master branch

Answer (score 0):

first make a `git pull` and after that make a `git push`

Comment: i already did that but the same error is coming up.