# viewing history of commit conflicts on github

Tags: github, version-control, merge-conflict-resolution

On github, is there a way to see all the previous commits in a repository that resulted in a conflict and require human to resolve at the end?

Edit: if I try to push an update to the repo and it resulted in a conflict, does github records that at all? I can definitely see if on my local clone.

Comment: See : https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-previous-commits/

Comment: how do you see that conflict in your local clone?

Comment: when it complains that I can't push the commit because there is a conflict...

Comment: Ok, the git which does the complaining is the local one then, GitHub doesn't record anything regarding conflict on its side.

Comment: What error message do you see when you try to push to GitHub? This one? (http://stackoverflow.com/q/1713137/6309)

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.
You have a tool which allows you to pinpoints the commits causing conflicts *during* a merge (see "[How can I find out which Git commits cause conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18162930/6309)")

But once the merge is done, the resolution information is not recorded with it.
(a [mechanism like git rerere](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html) is only local to your clone, not on the GitHub side)

Answer (score 0):

Github does not do it but another tool can be used to have a track on GitHub. [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) which comes with ([git-gui](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui)) automatically includes the conflicts in the merge commit. So it is recorded in the github.com in merge comments automatically. One can look in the history of each file individually it see the changes.

An example comment is like:

```
Precedes: 

    Merge branch 'upstream_master' into local_master

    # Conflicts:
    #   lib/Styles/variables.scss
    #   lib/Views/UserInterface.jsx
    #   wwwroot/config.json
    #   wwwroot/favicons/manifest.json
    #   wwwroot/index.html
```