# How to find the commits that caused a merge conflict?

Tags: git

I already saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162930/how-can-i-find-out-which-git-commits-cause-conflicts) and a few others, but couldn't find any satisfactory answer.
My question is, when I try to `git merge`, and get a CONFLICT, is there an out-of-the-box way for me to find out which pair of commits caused the conflict? I'm not looking for another way to merge (rebase, imerge, etc.), it's just a skill I want to have to find the commits that caused the conflict when I only have git in hand.

Comment: Git doesn't keep track of conflicts once merged.

Comment: There's no builtin commands for figuring out which commits that causes the merge conflict, no. You could look into trying to automate it by iteratively merging one commit at a time, but that's probably not a good idea either because following commits might fix the problem before the merge. A different approach would be to figure out which lines are causing the conflict, and then use git blame to figure out where they came from.