# Sourcetree merge broken solution

Tags: git, visual-studio, merge, atlassian-sourcetree

I am just tried to do my first merge in Git using Sourcetree and it seems to have broken my project. It builds okay but errors at runtime.

The error I am getting is: 
Could not load file or assembly 'SMyProject_LOCAL_8996' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

According to this: [In a git merge conflict, what are the BACKUP, BASE, LOCAL, and REMOTE files that are generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381677/in-a-git-merge-conflict-what-are-the-backup-base-local-and-remote-files-that)

There should be remote, local etc which I assume is causing the problem.

As a hidden file in my project (MVC Web App) there is the bin directory, unloaded, which contains a dll of the same name as in the error.

But for the life of me I can't find a reference to the assembly and I cannot find a way to resolve the issue.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: That almost sounds like a cached version of the DLL mixing things up  Have you tried clearing out your ASP.NET temporary files?  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files" for 32-bit or "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319" for 64-bit.