# Vimdiff equivalent for Select Lines

Tags: vimdiff, kdiff3

When used as a [mergetool for Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904644/how-do-i-use-vimdiff-to-resolve-a-conflict), what is the equivalent in vimdiff to kdiff3's "Select Lines(s) From A/B/C"? Is there a shortcut for that like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>2</kbd>/<kbd>3</kbd> in kdiff3?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Vim Reference Manual section for vimdiff](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html#vimdiff), there are no built-in commands with the full functionality of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>2</kbd>/<kbd>3</kbd> in vimdiff. What I mean by "full functionality" is that in kdiff3 you could do the commands <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> in that order, and in the merged version you end up with the diff lines from buffer B followed by the lines from buffer C followed by the lines from buffer A.

There is, however, a command for performing a more limited version of the functionality available in kdiff3. If you only want to use lines from one of your input files, then the command `[count]`<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> is available, where `[count]` is typically <kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>2</kbd>, or <kbd>3</kbd> depending on which vim buffer you want to pull the lines from. (<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> stands for "diff obtain".)

For example, if you had the following merge situation:
[image: vimdiff merge situation]
then you could move your cursor to the merge conflict in the bottom buffer and type <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> if you wanted "monkey", <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> if you wanted "pig", or <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> if you wanted "whale".

If you do need to grab lines from multiple buffers when merging with vimdiff, then my recommendation would be to set the Git config option merge.conflictstyle to diff3 (`git config merge.conflictstyle diff3`) so that the common ancestor appears in the merged buffer of the file, as shown in the screenshot above. Then just move the lines around to your liking using vim commands and delete the diff notations and any unused lines.